# LinkedBlockingQueue. Как добавлять элемент в очередь, убирая самый старый?

Tags: java, многопоточность, очередь

Например, задали размер `LinkedBlockingQueue` = 2. Когда пытаемся положить третий элемент, поток, пытающийся положить данные, зависает. Как сделать так, чтобы при попытке положить третий элемент, удалялся самый старый элемент, а новый вставал в очередь.

Может есть специальная очередь для этого даже?

Comment: В Google Guava есть [EvictingQueue](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html), которая делает то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkedBlockingQueue` - это специальная очередь, задача которой блокировать поток, а не дропать первый вошедший элемент.

Для Вашей же задачи достаточно написать простенький метод в вашем коде для вставки значения (или создать наследника `LinkedBlockingQueue` и переопределить вставку): проверка текущего кол-ва элементов на максимальное значение и удаление первого элемента в этом случае.

Или создать наследника любой конкурентной очереди, добавив конструктор с максимальным значением и переопределить вставку.